Inductance of two infinite conducting cylinders forming an infinite loop with current flowing through
I recently came across the following question:

Two infinite long conducting cylinders with radius $a$ are parallel apart and the separation between the central axes of the cylinder is $D$. There is a uniform current $I$ which are counter propagating in two cylinders. The system forms an infinite loop with current $I$ flowing through it. In this problem, we assume $a \ll D$. Calculate the self-inductance per unit length of the infinite loop.


At first glance, I thought that, since the current through the two conducting cylinders are flowing in opposite directions, the net magnetic flux should be $0$, which means that the self-inductance of the infinite loop is $0$?
This can be shown quantitatively, since the net magnetic field at distance $x$ to the right of the central axis of the left cylinder (between the two cylinders) is given by Ampere's law as:
$$B = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi (x)}-\frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi (D-x)}$$
giving the magnetic flux through $l$ meters of the loop as:
\begin{align}
\Phi_B &= \int^l_0\int^{D-a}_a \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi (x)}-\frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi (D-x)} dx dy\\
&= \int^l_0 \left[\frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi}\ln(x) + \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi}\ln(D-x)\right]^{D-a}_a dy\\
&= 0
\end{align}
However, the problem solution calculates the flux into the by each cylinder as:
\begin{align}
\Phi_1 = \Phi_2 &= \int^l_0\int^{D-a}_a \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi x} dx dy\\
&= \frac{\mu_0 Il}{2\pi}\ln\left(\frac{D-a}{a}\right)
\end{align}
Then adds them together to get total magnetic flux as: $\Phi_B =\frac{\mu_0 Il}{\pi}\ln\left(\frac{D-a}{a}\right)$
And then evaluates the self-inductance per unit length of the loop to be:
$$L = \frac{\Phi_B}{Il} = \frac{\mu_0}{\pi}\ln\left(\frac{D-a}{a}\right)$$
This is probably some misconception, but I am confused as to why the magnitude of the magnetic flux by the two cylinders can just be summed up without considering the sign, when calculating the self-inductance.
I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help explain this to me. Thanks in advance!

They did account for the signs. One current is going up, the other is going down, and you want the flux through a surface that is on the opposite side of each wire. Check the signs again.

@Peltio Why is the surface on the opposite side for each wire? Isn’t the area vector of the surface fixed?

The upward current will have the magnetic field going counterclockwise (seen from the top of the current arrow) - B will go into the paper in the region between wires. The downward arrow will have the magnetic field going clockwise around the wire - B will still go into the paper in the region between wires. The fields, and their fluxed add up in the region between the wires.

OHH, I didn't even realise I was using my left hand for the direction of the field from the left wire! Thanks for clearing that up!
